# C# .net remoting Chat client/server

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a program that would be a peer to peer chat system. Were each launch of the program would initialize a Client and a Server.

I have Client1 that can send messages to Server2, but I have yet to find a way to get the messages to display on Client2's Chat screen.

Since I have to start the server before I start the Clients, is there a way to pass information between the 2 servers?

I have Client, Server and Class1 which is used by the Server side for data.

Comment: Try using SignalR. It helps handle these situations easily.

Comment: There are abundant examples for this on the web. If you have a more specific question, you'll get better answers.

Comment: How do I get he information passed to Server2 to display onto Client2's chat window? I have information passed to Server2 displaying in the CMD but I cannot figure out how to get it to display on Client2. so:

Client 1 says: hi
Server 2 get hi and sends to Client 2

Comment: @user1812667 - Post your code if you got a question about how to do something.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to send messages client/server or server/server

Comment: is there no other way to do it without installing a 3rd party system?